# VBA find duplicate in selected cells and count them

Tags: excel, vba, count, duplicates

I read many post on this forum regarding my problem, but cant find solutions.
I have a table with different number of cells, with duplicate value.
I would like to count duplicates and show in another columns.

Source table where I mark a few cell:

[image]

I would like to receive such output

[image]

A have a part of code, but whatever I select, it counts the last cell

```
Dim rng, rngTarget, rngTargetName As Range
Set rngTarget = Range("D7")

Set items = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each rng In Selection
       If Not items.exists(rng.Value) Then
        items.Add rng.Value, 1
        rngTarget.Value = items(rng.Value)
        rngTargetName = rng
    Else
        items(rng.Value) = items(rng.Value) + 1
        rngTarget.Value = items(rng.Value)
        rngTargetName = rng
    End If

Next
```

What i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gary's for help, but ...
i completed my version of code and now works as expected - i can select few cell and count duplicates.

My working code:

```
 Dim rng As Range
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each rng In Selection
        If rng <> "" Then
            If D.exists(rng.Value) Then
                D(rng.Value) = D(rng.Value) + 1
            Else
                D.Add rng.Value, 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each var In D.Keys
        Range("C" & (i + 18)) = var
        Range("E" & (i + 18)) = D(var)
        i = i + 1
    Next
Set D = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

First enter this in a Standard Module:

```
Public Function unikue(rng As Range)
    Dim arr, c As Collection, r As Range
    Dim nCall As Long, nColl As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Set c = New Collection
    
    nCall = Application.Caller.Count
    
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each r In rng
            If r.Value <> "" Then
                c.Add r.Text, CStr(r.Text)
            End If
        Next r
    On Error GoTo 0
    nColl = c.Count
    
    
    If nCall > nColl Then
        ReDim arr(1 To nCall, 1 To 1)
        For i = 1 To nCall
            arr(i, 1) = ""
        Next i
    Else
        ReDim arr(1 To nColl, 1 To 1)
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To nColl
        arr(i, 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next i
    
    unikue = arr
End Function
```

The above UDF() will return a list of the unique, non-blank, items in a block of cells.

Then in a set of cells in column, say **F** starting at **F5** ,  array-enter:

```
=unikue(A1:D3)
```

In **G5** enter:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$D$3,F5)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

With **Excel 365**, there is a no-VBA solution.